# Character conversion failure in ETL from Postgres UTF8 to SQLServer

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, character-encoding, ssis

I'm developing a piece of ETL which copies data from a data warehouse on Postgres which is using the UTF8 character set and running on Linux to an SQLServer using the typical Windows character set, via the standard Postgres ODBC driver.

I find that some of my source data contains UTF8 characters which can't be translated into the target character set, which cause the entire load to fail.

Is there a postgres function I can use to convert the data coming out of the database?  Are there any other ways to address this issue?

P.S. BTW, why does encountering this error in on data flow for one table cause all of my loads to fail?

Comment: There are several key pieces of information missing: what versions of PostgreSQL and SQL Server; what data types are the source and target columns; what is the target character set ("typical" means something different to everyone); are you referring to the Windows OS character set or to the SQL Server collation; do you have any transformations in your data flow? SQL Server [supports Unicode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143503(v=sql.105).aspx) (have you read the documentation?), but as a complete guess your destination column is `VARCHAR` when it should be `NVARCHAR`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a UTF-8 encoded character not supported in your target encoding, PostgreSQL has no way to convert it without destroying data. It won't destroy data, so it reports an error.

```
regress=# CREATE TABLE encoding_test(data text);
CREATE TABLE
regress=# INSERT INTO encoding_test(data) VALUES ('退休慰問金省182億怎麼用？ 藍中常委建議發消費券');
INSERT 0 1
regress=# SHOW client_encoding;
 client_encoding 
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)

regress=# SET client_encoding = 'Windows-1252';
SET
regress=# SELECT * FROM encoding_test ;
ERROR:  character 0xe98080 of encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in "WIN1252"
```

As for why that causes everything to stop working: When Pg raises an error, that aborts the transaction. Future statements in the same transaction will fail. That's by design, as preserving data integrity is important, and in a transaction if one operation fails the whole transaction should fail. It reduces the chances that errors will go un-noticed until someone restores a table and then asks "So, .... why is this one table empty?".

What you should do here is use the PostgreSQL Unicode ODBC driver, or use the ANSI ODBC driver with the utf-8 `client_encoding`, then insert the data into SQL Server as Unicode with a DB properly set up to accept Unicode.

If you actually want to destroy data by converting it to one of the Windows 8-bit codepages: PostgreSQL has no conversion mode where it substitutes non-convertable characters with a placeholder. This is occasionally frustrating when you *do* want to intentionally throw data away. I'd recommend keeping your PostgreSQL connection in UTF-8 mode or (in Windows) using the Unicode ODBC driver, then converting the strings from Unicode to your desired target encoding in your application, munging them as required.

Answer (score 1):

I am making some assumptions here.

1. You are trying to connect to Postgress using MS SQL Linked Objects via an ODBC System DSN, and see errors such as "ERROR: character 0xc280 of encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in "WIN1252";
2. Select statements on some tables work and other throw this error.

Fix: Use an ODBC driver that supports Unicode. I am using an ODBC driver from PostgreSQL Global Development Group. Go to Configure DSN/Manage DSN and select the Unicode driver.

Tried posting an image but the system wont accept - apparently I need to have 10 "reputation" to post.

Good luck.

Madhu